# I want to write certain texts next to textViews

Tags: android, kotlin, math, text

[image]

How can I add the "%" symbol and the "kWh" unit in the box as in the image? I tried going to the .xml file and adding it to the text or hint part, but I couldn't keep the text in the middle and place these indicators to the left and right.

```
var verim = Math.round((((lsize * pcs) / (air * cel)) * ((lslop * pco) / (air * sun))))
        if (verim >= 100){
            verim = (90..99).random().toLong()
        }
```

This is the code to put the '%' sign.

```
 val energy = Math.round(((lsize * pco) + (lslop * pcs)) / 100)
```

This is where the unit 'kWh' should be put.

XML codes.

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/verimText"
    android:layout_width="108dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="(%)"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.831"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.253" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/energyText"
    android:layout_width="108dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="(kWh)"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.831"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.431" />
```

Comment: Please post your xml code here for the solution.

Comment: "I tried going to the .xml file", xml code please...

Comment: I added the xml codes

Comment: When I make the text aligment right or left, instead of just getting the '%' symbol and the 'kWh' unit, it also justifies the result to the right or left.